# Cypress CSS Locator I am trying to click an element from a list but it says Your subject contained 4 elements

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, selenium-webdriver, cypress

I have a UI with a list of elements, 2 columns. The first columns shows the name of the item e.g. Manager, Operator and the list will grow The 2nd column is a colour picker element. You can choose a colour.  I am trying to click a colour from the colour picker element for a name e.g. for Manager .I want to iterate over the elements and find the colour picker element for Manager and click the green colour.

I have the following code snippet for my method (Resource is a parameter, the value will be Manager, Operator etc)

```
static getAudienceColour3(Resource:string): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> {        
    return cy.get("li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] span[class='form-control']")
    .each(function($el, index, $listOfElements) {            
        //return cy.get('arm-colour-picker[ng-reflect-input-id="colourPicker_1"] div span')
        switch(Resource) { 
            case 'Manager': { 
                //return cy.get('arm-colour-picker[ng-reflect-input-id="colourPicker_1"] div span')
                return cy.get("li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] span[class='form-control']").contains(Resource)    
                .parents('.row').within(() => {                         
                    cy.get('span.colour-select') // gets the colour picker
                    .find('ul li[tabindex="3"]');   // gets the green colour which is at tabindex="3"                                                              
                }); 
                
            }                                                        
           case 'Operator': { 
                return cy.get("li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] span[class='form-control']").contains(Resource)    
                .parents('.row').within(() => {                         
                    cy.get('span.colour-select')   // gets the color-picker                                            
                    .find('ul li[tabindex="33"]');   // gets the blue colour which is at tabindex="33"                                                              
                });                                                             
            }                                                        
            case 'Miner': { 
                return cy.get("li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] span[class='form-control']").contains(Resource)    
                .parents('.row').within(() => {                         
                    cy.get('span.colour-select')   // gets the color-picker                                            
                    .find('ul li[tabindex="51"]');   // gets the red colour which is at tabindex="51"                                                              
                });                                                             
            } 
        }
    });
```

From my spec.ts test i call the method as follows

```
Audience.getAudienceColour3('Manager').click();
```

When the test runs the error is

```
cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 4 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially click each element.
```

How do i click li[tabindex="3"] which is the green colour for Manager element?
I will then add another test to click the e.g. blue colour for Operator and so on

The HTML snippet is

```
<li _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" cdkdrag="" class="cdk-drag item container-fluid" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-data="[object Object]" ng-reflect-disabled="false" rowid="657" orderid="0">
<div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="row">
<div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-1 form-check">...</div>
<div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-3">
<arm-colour-picker _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" name="colourPicker" ng-reflect-input-id="colourPicker_1" ng-reflect-colour-id="-2">
<div class="arm-colour-picker" title="1">
<span tabindex="0" class="colour-select" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span>
<input type="hidden" id="colourPicker_1" ng-reflect-name="colourPicker_1_dropdown" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" value="[object Object]" ng-reflect-model="[object Object]"><ul class="expand"><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="0" style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">  <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="selected dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="1" style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"> 1 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="2" style="border-color: rgb(102, 102, 51); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(102, 102, 51);"> 2 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="3" style="border-color: rgb(102, 102, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(102, 102, 0);"> 3 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="4" style="border-color: rgb(153, 153, 102); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(153, 153, 102);"> 4 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="5" style="border-color: rgb(153, 153, 153); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);"> 5 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="6" style="border-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"> 6 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="7" style="border-color: rgb(204, 204, 153); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(204, 204, 153);"> 7 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="8" style="border-color: rgb(204, 255, 102); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(204, 255, 102);"> 8 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="9" style="border-color: rgb(204, 255, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(204, 255, 0);"> 9 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="10" style="border-color: rgb(204, 204, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(204, 204, 0);"> 10 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="11" style="border-color: rgb(153, 255, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(153, 255, 0);"> 11 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="12" style="border-color: rgb(153, 255, 51); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(153, 255, 51);"> 12 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="13" style="border-color: rgb(153, 204, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(153, 204, 0);"> 13 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="14" style="border-color: rgb(102, 153, 51); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(102, 153, 51);"> 14 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="15" style="border-color: rgb(102, 153, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(102, 153, 0);"> 15 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="16" style="border-color: rgb(51, 153, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(51, 153, 0);"> 16 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="17" style="border-color: rgb(0, 153, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(0, 153, 0);"> 17 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="18" style="border-color: rgb(0, 204, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(0, 204, 0);"> 18 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="19" style="border-color: rgb(0, 204, 102); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(0, 204, 102);"> 19 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="20" style="border-color: rgb(102, 204, 102); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(102, 204, 102);"> 20 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="21" style="border-color: rgb(0, 255, 102); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(0, 255, 102);"> 21 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="22" style="border-color: rgb(102, 255, 102); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(102, 255, 102);"> 22 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="23" style="border-color: rgb(102, 204, 153); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(102, 204, 153);"> 23 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="24" style="border-color: rgb(0, 255, 153); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(0, 255, 153);"> 24 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="25" style="border-color: rgb(0, 204, 153); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(0, 204, 153);"> 25 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="26" style="border-color: rgb(0, 153, 153); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(0, 153, 153);"> 26 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="27" style="border-color: rgb(0, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);"> 27 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="28" style="border-color: rgb(153, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(153, 255, 255);"> 28 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="29" style="border-color: rgb(153, 204, 204); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(153, 204, 204);"> 29 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="30" style="border-color: rgb(0, 153, 204); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(0, 153, 204);"> 30 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="31" style="border-color: rgb(0, 102, 255); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(0, 102, 255);"> 31 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="32" style="border-color: rgb(51, 51, 255); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(51, 51, 255);"> 32 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="33" style="border-color: rgb(0, 0, 255); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"> 33 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="34" style="border-color: rgb(102, 0, 204); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(102, 0, 204);"> 34 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="35" style="border-color: rgb(153, 51, 204); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(153, 51, 204);"> 35 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="36" style="border-color: rgb(255, 153, 204); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 153, 204);"> 36 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="37" style="border-color: rgb(255, 102, 153); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 102, 153);"> 37 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="38" style="border-color: rgb(255, 0, 204); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 0, 204);"> 38 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="39" style="border-color: rgb(204, 0, 153); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(204, 0, 153);"> 39 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="40" style="border-color: rgb(204, 102, 153); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(204, 102, 153);"> 40 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="41" style="border-color: rgb(204, 153, 153); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(204, 153, 153);"> 41 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="42" style="border-color: rgb(153, 102, 102); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(153, 102, 102);"> 42 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="43" style="border-color: rgb(204, 102, 102); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(204, 102, 102);"> 43 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="44" style="border-color: rgb(153, 51, 51); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(153, 51, 51);"> 44 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="45" style="border-color: rgb(153, 102, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(153, 102, 0);"> 45 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="46" style="border-color: rgb(153, 51, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(153, 51, 0);"> 46 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="47" style="border-color: rgb(204, 102, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(204, 102, 0);"> 47 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="48" style="border-color: rgb(204, 102, 51); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(204, 102, 51);"> 48 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="49" style="border-color: rgb(204, 0, 51); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(204, 0, 51);"> 49 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="50" style="border-color: rgb(204, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);"> 50 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="51" style="border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"> 51 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="52" style="border-color: rgb(255, 51, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 51, 0);"> 52 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="53" style="border-color: rgb(255, 51, 51); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 51, 51);"> 53 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="54" style="border-color: rgb(255, 102, 51); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 102, 51);"> 54 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="55" style="border-color: rgb(255, 102, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 102, 0);"> 55 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="56" style="border-color: rgb(255, 153, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);"> 56 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="57" style="border-color: rgb(255, 204, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 204, 0);"> 57 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="58" style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);"> 58 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="59" style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 102); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 102);"> 59 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="dark" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="60" style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 153); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 153);"> 60 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></li><li class="light" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="61" style="border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"> 61 <span class="fas fa-check icon" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></li>
<div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-1 float-right"><span _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" cdkdraghandle="" class="cdk-drag-handle fa fa-bars order-button" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; user-select: none;"></span></div>
<div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-1 float-right"><button _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" type="button" class="delete far fa-times"></button>
<li _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" cdkdrag="" class="cdk-drag item container-fluid" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-data="[object Object]" ng-reflect-disabled="false" rowid="658" orderid="0"><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="row"><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-1 form-check"><input _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" type="checkbox" title="" ng-reflect-name="checked-658" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"></div><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-5"><span _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="form-control" title="" data-disabled="false">Operator</span><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-3">
<div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-1 float-right"><span _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" cdkdraghandle="" class="cdk-drag-handle fa fa-bars order-button" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; user-select: none;"></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-1 float-right"><button _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" type="button" class="delete far fa-times"></button><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><!--bindings={}--></div></div></li><!--container--><li _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" cdkdrag="" class="cdk-drag item container-fluid" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-data="[object Object]" ng-reflect-disabled="false" rowid="659" orderid="0"><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="row"><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-1 form-check"><input _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" type="checkbox" title="" ng-reflect-name="checked-659" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"></div><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-5"><span _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="form-control" title="" data-disabled="false">Miner</span><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-3"><arm-colour-picker _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" name="colourPicker" ng-reflect-input-id="colourPicker_3" ng-reflect-colour-id="-2"><div class="arm-colour-picker" title="1"><span tabindex="0" class="colour-select" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span><input type="hidden" id="colourPicker_3" ng-reflect-name="colourPicker_3_dropdown" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" value="[object Object]" ng-reflect-model="[object Object]"><!--bindings={}--></div></arm-colour-picker><!--ng-container--><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-1 float-right"><span _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" cdkdraghandle="" class="cdk-drag-handle fa fa-bars order-button" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; user-select: none;"></span></div>
<div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-1 float-right"><button _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" type="button" class="delete far fa-times"></button>
<div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="footer container-fluid"><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="row"><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-1"><select _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" id="pageSize" name="pageSize" class="pagesize ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-name="pageSize" ng-reflect-model="10"><option _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" value="10" ng-reflect-value="10">10</option><option _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" value="25" ng-reflect-value="25">25</option><option _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" value="50" ng-reflect-value="50">50</option><option _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" value="100" ng-reflect-value="100">100</option></select></div><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-3"><span _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="totalrecords">4 of 4 records</span></div><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="col-sm-8"><nav _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" aria-label="Page navigation"><ul _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="pagination pagination-sm justify-content-end"><li _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="page-item disabled" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"><a _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="fa fa-angle-double-left page-link"></a></li><li _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="page-item disabled" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"><a _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="fa fa-angle-left page-link"></a></li><li _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="page-item active" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"><a _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="page-link">1</a></li>
<li _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="page-item disabled" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"><a _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="fa fa-angle-right page-link"></a></li><li _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="page-item disabled" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"><a _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="fa fa-angle-double-right page-link"></a></li></ul><nav _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="navbar navbar-nav navbar-bottom fixed-bottom"><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="container"><div _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center mx-auto"><button _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" type="button" id="Save" class="btn-arm" disabled="">Save</button><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><button _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" type="button" id="AddNew" class="btn-arm">Add</button><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><button _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" type="button" id="Delete" class="btn-arm" disabled="">Delete</button><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><button _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" type="button" id="Cancel" class="btn-arm navbar-btn">Close</button><button _ngcontent-ptu-c336="" type="button" id="Help" armhelp="Drop_Down_config.htm" class="btn-arm helpbutton navbar-btn" ng-reflect-arm-help="Drop_Down_config.htm">Help</button></div></div></nav></arm-list-view>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot sample of how the UI looks for the elements
[image]

Thank you for your help and suggestions

I have tried the following

```
static getAudienceColour(Resource:string): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> {            
        const colorIndexes = {  // a lookup object for colors
            'Manager': 3,
            'Operator': 33,
            'Miner': 51
        }              
          const colorIndex = colorIndexes[Resource];              
          let result;              
          const selector = "li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] span[class='form-control']"              
          return cy.get(selector)
            .each($el => {              
              const colorIndex = colorIndexes[Resource];              
              result = cy.contains(selector, Resource)    
                .parents('.row')
                .find('span.colour-select')
                .find(`ul li[tabindex="${colorIndex}"]`);                    
            })
            .then(() => {
              return result
            })                
    }
```

I get the error on line
const colorIndex = colorIndexes[Resource];

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ Manager: number; Operator: number; Miner: number; }'.
```

No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ Manager: number; Operator: number; Miner: number; }

Riaz

Comment: It's saying that `find` is returning more than 1 element so it doesn't know what to click¸are you sure your `parents('.row').within` is selecting only the parent you want?

Comment: Not sure how to solve the typescript error, but you can substitute `const colorIndex = Resource === 'Manager' ? 3 : Resource === 'Operator' ? 33 : 51;`

Comment: BTW where does Resource come from? Is it a parameter?

Comment: Yes, it's a param - see top function. Probably what causes the error, since `Resource:string` is strongly typed.

Answer (score 1):

The method is only returning `cy.get("li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] span[class='form-control']")`.

You cannot return something inside `.each()`, Cypress uses the return value to indicate early breaking of the loop

[Docs .each() - The original array is always yielded](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#DOM-Elements)

> No matter what is returned in the callback function, .each() will always yield the original array.

[Docs .each() - Return early](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#Return-early)

> You can stop the .each() loop early by returning false in the callback function.

Use a `.then()` to return something different

```js
let result;
return cy.get("li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] span[class='form-control']")
  .each($el => {
    // searching code here
    result = ... item found, assign it to result variable
  })
  .then(() => {
    return result  // modifies the return value above
  })
```

---

**Other problems**

The way you are doing `cy.get(selector).contains(Resource)` probably does not work as a filter the way you expect.

Use `cy.contains(selector, Resource)` instead.

---

You can simplify the `switch` part by using a lookup object

```js
const colorIndexes = {  // a lookup object for colors
  'Manager': 3
  'Operator': 33
  'Miner': 51
}

const colorIndex = colorIndexes[Resource];

cy.get(...).find(`ul li[tabindex="${colorIndex}"]`);  // instead of switch
```

---

`find()` in logically equivalent to `within()`, but simpler in this case

```js
const colorIndexes = {  // a lookup object for colors
  'Manager': 3
  'Operator': 33
  'Miner': 51
}

const colorIndex = colorIndexes[Resource];

let result;

const selector = "li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] span[class='form-control']"

return cy.get(selector)
  .each($el => {

    const colorIndex = colorIndexes[Resource];

    result = cy.contains(selector, Resource)    
      .parents('.row')
      .find('span.colour-select')
      .find(`ul li[tabindex="${colorIndex}"]`);                    
  })
  .then(() => {
    return result
  })
```

---

With the correct `.contains()` you probably don't even need the `.each()`, so the original problem goes away

```js
const colorIndexes = {  // a lookup object for colors
  'Manager': 3
  'Operator': 33
  'Miner': 51
}

const colorIndex = colorIndexes[Resource];

const selector = "li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] span[class='form-control']"

return cy.contains(selector, Resource)    
  .parents('.row')
  .find('span.colour-select')
  .find(`ul li[tabindex="${colorIndex}"]`);                    
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I have posted my method at the bottom of my question above with error I get. on line const colorIndex = colorIndexes[Resource];  I get the error Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ Manager: number; Operator: number; Miner: number; }'.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I put your code into a typrescript file, but can't get the error. I added the Resource parameter as string, as per your original `static getAudienceColour(Resource:string)` and also added `/// <reference types="cypress" />` at the top of the file.

Comment: If you still can't resolve it, I endorse the suggestion to try with `const colorIndex: number = Resource === 'Manager' ? 3 : Resource === 'Operator' ? 33 : 51;`

Comment: Note, you also have `const colorIndex = colorIndexes[Resource];` twice, but only once is necessary (use it in either place, since Resource does not change within the `.each()` loop).